# Error while dropping column from a table with secondary index (Scylladb)

Tags: scylla

While dropping a column from a table that contains secondary index I get the following error. I am using ScyllaDB version 3.0.4.

[Invalid query] message="Cannot drop column name on base table warehouse.myuser with materialized views"

Below are the example commands

```
create table myuser (id int primary key, name text, email text);
create index on myuser(email);
alter table myuser drop name;
```

I can successfully run the above statements in Apache Cassandra.

Answer (score 6):

Default secondary indexes in Scylla are global and implemented on top of materialized views (as opposed to Apache Cassandra's local indexing implementation), which gives them new possibilities, but also adds certain restrictions. Dropping a column from a table with materialized views is a complex operation, especially if the target column is selected by one of the views or its liveness can affect view row liveness. In order to avoid these problems, dropping a column is unconditionally not possible when there are materialized views attached to a table. The error you see is a combination of that and the fact that Scylla's index uses a materialized view underneath to store corresponding base keys for each row.

The obvious workaround is to drop the index first, then drop the column and recreate the index, but that of course takes time and resources.

However, in some cases columns can be allowed to be dropped from the base table even if it has materialized views, especially if the column is not selected in the view and its liveness does not have any impact on view rows. For reference, I created an issue that requests implementing it in our bug tracker: https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/4448

Comment: Abasar, thanks for reporting this issue. I sent a patch to issue 4448 and it was already committed and will work if you're compiling the master branch yourself - or will eventually appear in a future release. You can now remove any non-indexed column, except the special case where you indexd one of the primary-key columns - only in that special case you can't remove any column, because every column is important for determining liveness of rows.